# Not retrieving data from script tag with Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to retrieve data from a script tag that I'll attach below. From that script tag I would need the following data: `digitalData.product.pvi_type_name`   , `digitalData.product.pvi_subtype_name`
, `digitalData.product.model_name`, `digitalData.product.displayName`.
I have written my own program in Python for retrieving but it doesn't work for now...

Script Tag Structure:

```
<script>
var COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS = "buy";
var COUNTRY_SHOP_URL = "./buy";
var COUNTRY_WHERE_URL = "";
try {digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_2 = "mobile";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_3 = "mobile";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_4 = "smartphones";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_5 = "galaxy-note9";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.product.pvi_type_name      = "Mobile";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.product.pvi_subtype_name   = "Smartphone";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.product.model_name         = "SM-N960";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.product.displayName        = "galaxy note9";} catch(e) {}
try {digitalData.product.category           = digitalData.page.pathIndicator.depth_3;} catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Python Script:

```
import scrapy
import csv
import re

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    with open('input.csv','r') as csvf:
        urlreader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        for url in urlreader:
            if url[0]=="y":
                yield scrapy.Request(url[1])

def parse(self, response):
    def get_values(parameter, script):
        return re.findall('%s = "(.*)"' % parameter, script)[0]

    source_arr = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'COUNTRY_SHOP_STATUS')]/text()").extract()
    if source_arr:
          source = source_arr[0]
          with open('output.csv', 'a',newline='') as csvfile:
              fieldnames = ['Category', 'Type', 'Model', 'SK']
              writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
              writer.writerow({'Category': get_values("pvi_type_name", source), 'Type': get_values("pvi_subtype_name", source), 'Model': get_values("pathIndicator.depth_5", source), 'SK': get_values("model_name", source)})
```

Comment: and by *...but it doesn't work for now...* you mean...? Share current and desired output

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andersson! It simply doesn't return the information I need. None of the "Category, Type, Model, SK" are filled with data.

Comment: Did you check (print out) `source_arr`? Does page source contain target content in `script` node or it's a dynamic content?

Comment: @Andersson print(source_arr) returns empty. The url I'm trying to scrape is : "https://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-note9/'. It contains that script tag.

Comment: I can get required script with `requests` + `lxml.html` using same XPath, so it's definitely not an XPath issue

Comment: I managed to get the script tag @Andersson! My current problem is that in "source_arr" I store all the information from that script tag, and I only need few values from it..

Comment: Did you try anything to parse `script` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got `script` content, try below to get required values:

```
import re

result = re.findall('product.*"(.*)"', source_arr[0])
print(result)
# ['Mobile', 'Smartphone', 'SM-N960', 'galaxy note9']
```

Comment: Another quick question @Andersson. If I want to select only one it would be like this: "categorie = re.findall('product.pvi_type_name"(.*)"', source_arr[0])" ?

Comment: `categorie = re.findall('product.pvi_type_name.*"(.*)"', source_arr[0])`